# Use a remote desktop viewer from an iMac to a remote workstation through VPN

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, vpn, osx-leopard

I have an iMac on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard and I connect to my workplace through a VPN connection. To this point everything is ok.

But I'd like to use a remote desktop viewer, with a good quality, and free, does it exist on Mac? I'm getting tired of using Boot Camp and start Windows...

Comment: So, what OS is that remote workstation? (I guess people are right assuming Windows, as you apparently have *some* viewer in Windows?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads.mspx?pid=Mactopia_RDC&fid=CD9EC77E-5B07-4332-849F-046611458871#viewer) from Microsoft.

There is also an open source RDC called [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/).

I use both and they work well.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RDC Mac free](http://mac-gratuit.fr/telecharger/RDC.html), here in french. Not so good resolution, but free and works!